# rpc.ServerCodec Still Serving?

Tags: go, tcp, rpc, json-rpc

I was performing some RPC tests, and stumbled across a problem I can't seem to solve. In my testing I create three separate RPC servers, all of which I try to close and shutdown. However upon performing my last test (TestRpcCodecServerClientComm), it seems my client connection is connecting to the first RPC server I started (I know this because I at some point attached IDs to the RPCHandlers), even though I attempted everything I could to make sure it was shutdown. Though the code is not there I have attempted to inspect every single error I could, but that did not bring about anything.

#### rpc.go

```
package rbot

import (
    "io"
    "net"
    "net/rpc"
    "net/rpc/jsonrpc"
)

func RpcCodecClientWithPort(port string) (rpc.ClientCodec, error) {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:"+port)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return jsonrpc.NewClientCodec(conn), nil
}

func RpcCodecServer(conn io.ReadWriteCloser) rpc.ServerCodec {
    return jsonrpc.NewServerCodec(conn)
}
```

#### rpc_test.go

```
package rbot

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/rpc"
    "testing"
)

type RPCHandler struct {
    RPCServer net.Listener
    conn      rpc.ServerCodec
    done      chan bool
    TestPort  string
    stop      bool
    GotRPC    bool
}

func (r *RPCHandler) SetupTest() {
    r.stop = false
    r.GotRPC = false
    r.done = make(chan bool)
    r.TestPort = "5556"
}

// TODO: Create separate function to handle erroring
func (r *RPCHandler) CreateRPCServer() error {
    rpc.RegisterName("TestMaster", TestAPI{r})

    var err error
    r.RPCServer, err = net.Listen("tcp", ":"+r.TestPort)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := r.RPCServer.Accept()
            if err != nil || r.stop {
                r.done <- true
                return
            }
            r.conn = RpcCodecServer(conn)
            rpc.ServeCodec(r.conn)
        }
    }()
    return nil
}

func (r *RPCHandler) CloseRPCServer() error {
    r.stop = true
    if r.conn != nil {
        err := r.conn.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
    err := r.RPCServer.Close()
    <-r.done
    return err
}

type TestAPI struct {
    t *RPCHandler
}

func (tapi TestAPI) Send(msg string, result *string) error {
    if msg == "Got RPC?" {
        tapi.t.GotRPC = true
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("Didn't receive right message")
}

// Check if we can create and close an RPC server successfully using the RPC server codec.
func TestRpcCodecServer(t *testing.T) {
    r := RPCHandler{}
    r.SetupTest()

    err := r.CreateRPCServer()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Could not create rpc server! %s:", err.Error())
    }

    err = r.CloseRPCServer()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Could not close RPC server! %s:", err.Error())
    }
}

// Check if we can create a client without erroring.
func TestRpcCodecClientWithPortt(t *testing.T) {
    r := RPCHandler{}
    r.SetupTest()
    r.CreateRPCServer()
    defer r.CloseRPCServer()

    RPCClient, err := RpcCodecClientWithPort(r.TestPort)
    defer RPCClient.Close()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Could not create an RPC client! %s:", err.Error())
    }
}

// Let's double check and make sure our server and client can speak to each other
func TestRpcCodecServerClientComm(t *testing.T) {
    r := RPCHandler{}
    r.SetupTest()
    r.CreateRPCServer()
    defer r.CloseRPCServer()

    RPCCodec, _ := RpcCodecClientWithPort(r.TestPort)
    RPCClient := rpc.NewClientWithCodec(RPCCodec)
    defer RPCClient.Close()

    var result string
    err := RPCClient.Call("TestMaster.Send", "Got RPC?", &result)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Error while trying to send RPC message: %s", err.Error())
    }

    if !r.GotRPC {
        t.Fatalf("Could not send correct message over RPC")
    }
}
```

Not sure if I'm just mishandling the connection or something of the like, any help would be much appreciated.

**For the Record** The RPC api does receive the correct string message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the source of your problems, your test configuration has a few race conditions which you should take care of before they cause problems. Always check for issues with the `-race` option. You should also let the OS allocate the port so you don't run into conflicts. See for example how [`httptest.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server) works.

Your failure here is that you're not creating a new `rpc.Server` for each test, you're reusing the `rpc.DefaultServer`. The first call to `CreateRPCServer` registers a `TestAPI` under the name `TestMaster`. Each subsequent call uses the already registered instance.

If you create a new `rpc.Server` each time you setup the test and register a new TestAPI, the final test will pass.

```
srv := rpc.NewServer()
srv.RegisterName("TestMaster", testAPI)

...
// and then use srv to handle the new connection
srv.ServeCodec(RpcCodecServer(conn))
```

Comment: Ah I see! That solved that. Also many thanks for the extra feedback, I never knew I could check for race conditions!